# How can a pregnant lady have periods?

Tags: pregnancy-test

> Grace Meachim, 32, from West Sussex, was unaware that she was 37 weeks
> pregnant as she had no visible baby bump, was taking her contraceptive
> pill "religiously" and **still had periods**.

[Source](https://archive.is/C1Ow6)

How can a pregnant lady have periods?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: The answer is that tabloids will/do publish rubbish.

Comment: The fact that she was still having what she believed to be periods despite being on birth control pills should tell you something wasn't right. Suggest you lookup withdrawal bleeding.

Comment: A quick Google search can reveal the answer from many reputable sources.